# Reading XML with XDocument and LINQ Descendant Confusion

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to build a CSV file from the XML I'm working with. The XML is structured as follows:

```
<dt_type>
    <t_name>Commodities</t_name>
    <dt_category>
        <pc_name>ironore_steel</pc_name>  
        <dt_products>
            <p_name>iron</p_name> 
        </dt_products>
        <dt_products>
            <p_name>coiled steel</p_name> 
        </dt_products>
    </dt_category>
    <dt_category>
        <pc_name>rubber</pc_name>  
        <dt_products>
            <p_name>molten rubber</p_name> 
        </dt_products>
        <dt_products>
            <p_name>pressed rubber</p_name> 
        </dt_products>
    </dt_category>
</dt_type>
```

I want to build a CSV file like (t_name, pc_name, p_name)

The current code I have is this

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(output + "xmlSgx.txt");
//query xml
var xdata = from r in xdoc.Descendants("dt_category")
            select new
            {
                //tName = r.Element("t_name").Value,
                pcName = (string)r.Element("pc_name"),
                pName = (string)r.Element("dt_products").Element("p_name")
            };

foreach (var r in xdata)
{
    result.AppendLine(r.pcName + "," + r.pName);
}
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(output + "xmlRes.txt"))
{
    file.Write(result);
}
```

The best output I was able to produce was this:

```
ironore_steel,iron
rubber,molten rubber
```

I'm not even able to pull multiple  when I'm descending from

An example of what I want to pull:

```
Commodities,ironore_steel,iron
Commodities,ironore_steel,coiled steel
Commodities,rubber,molten rubber
Commodities,rubber,pressed rubber
```

Any nudge to the right direction will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Do you want t_name and pc_name repeated for each p_name? Post an example csv output of the xml specified

Comment: I edited my original post to include an example of what I'm trying to build out!

Answer (score 1):

You're only selecting a single node from each category.
This method will return each category as a line and you can push it into a text file using File.WriteAllLines

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetLines()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(data);
        var title = doc.Descendants("t_name").First().Value;
        var xdata = from r in doc.Descendants("dt_category")
        select title + "," + (string)r.Element("pc_name") + "," +  string.Join(",", r.Descendants("p_name").Select(e => e.Value.ToString()).ToArray());
        return xdata;
    }
```

**Updated after seeing the required output:**

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetLines2()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(data);
    var title = doc.Descendants("t_name").First().Value;
    var names = doc.Descendants("p_name");
    var lines = from n in names select title + "," + n.Parent.Parent.Descendants("pc_name").First().Name + "," + n.Value;
    return lines;
}
```

This has no exception handling.

Comment: I tried to use this solution but what I got was below:

Commodities,ironore_steel,iron,coiled steel
Commodities,rubber,molten rubber, pressed rubber

Comment: I thought from your original example that this was what you wanted.